# How to add methods to an xml in ie9

Tags: xml, internet-explorer-9, selectors-api

I was pretty disapointed when I discovered that ie9 doesn't accept querySelector on xml objects.
I was trying to pollyfill it, starting simple, like this:

```
xml["querySelector"] = function(tag){
    return this.getElementByTagName(tag)[0]
}
```

But even this throws an error. It seems like the xml object can't be modified.

The error I get in ie9 is: "SCRIPT438: The object doesn't accept this property or method"

Do you know of any solution for this?

Comment: "But even this throws an error" — What error?

Comment: The error is SCRIPT438: The object doesn¡t accept this property or method